# Signalling server, webrtc , android to android adhoc network

Tags: android, webrtc, adhoc, simplewebrtc, ad-hoc-network

Hello everyone,
              I have implemented the following demo on my android phone (Video broadcast for android,  https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/docs/ios-android.md#cordova-demos) .
 Now i want to find out the signalling server for android WiFi,which can be easily integrated with this demo. Signalling server have to work without internet but with ad-hoc networks. Is there any way that i can create an ad-hoc network using these android phones.

All communication between android phones is peer to peer.

and my final product will be an android app.

Comment: Did you try anything to accomplish your goals? If so please post your code (the important parts, not all).

Comment: Actually not because i think developing a signalling server from scratch is not possible for me as i am new to it.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. Stackoverflow is not for these kind of questions (advice on which software/product to use) as things might change fast. You are better of to search the web for such a server (maybe a site compares some, etc...)

Comment: @TahirAbbas Please use RTCMultiConnection github page for such features-request/issues: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/issues

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I have also posted it on the above mentioned link. Could please help me in finding solution as soon as possible. i just need to connect two android phone without access point. How can i replace this line of code for websocket or any other signalling server for not to use internet on android.
connection.socketURL= 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';

Regards,